# How can I undo/uninstall a local module setup with `python setup.py develop` or replace with an `easy_install`?

Tags: python, distutils, easy-install

When I'm working on module fork, I'll often add the fork (in progress) to the virtualenv of a full project for integrated testing, using

```
python setup.py develop
```

( which updates the easy_install.pth to point to the local copy )

When I'm done, the only way I've figured out how to clearly get rid of this, is to remove the entry from easy_install.pth or edit it to point to the already installed version.

I also can't `easy_install --upgrade` , because it realizes the development version is the latest.

I think pip could force the upgrade, but then it tries to reinstall every single dependency.

Does anyone have a good technique / strategy for managing this sort of stuff.  I know I'm missing something obvious here.